# Why does ui-router changes DOM structure of ui-views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create routing for my angular app using ui-router. I have basic concept example. What I need is for "this is map" to be displayed what ever the route is (always) but "this is about us" only when navigation to `#/about`.

index.html:

```
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.module.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.config.js'); ?>"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="jigup">
        <ui-view="nav"></ui-view>
        <ui-view="map"></ui-view>
        <ui-view="about"></ui-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('jigup', [
        'ui.router'
    ]);
})();
```

app.config.js:

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('jigup')
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/map');
            var map = {
                name: 'map',
                url: '/map',
                views: {
                    nav:{
                        template: '<a ui-sref="map">map</a><a ui-sref="about">About</a>'
                    },
                    map:{
                        template: 'this is map'
                    }
                }

            }

            var about = {
                name: 'about',
                url: '/about',
                views: {
                    nav:{
                        template: '<a ui-sref="map">map</a><a ui-sref="about">About</a>'
                    },
                    map:{
                        template: 'this is map'
                    },
                    about:{
                        template: 'this is about us'
                    }
                }
            }

            $stateProvider.state(map);
            $stateProvider.state(about);
        });

})();
```

When I navigate to my site `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/map');` does the job  and changes url to `..com/#/map` however I get blank page. When inspecting elements I saw something strange - DOM structure of ui-views:

```
<ui-view="nav">
    <ui-view="map">
        <ui-view="about">
        </ui-view="about">
    </ui-view="map">
</ui-view="nav">
```

Would appreciate if someone could tell me if this is expected DOM structure(because I strongly doubt that) or point out some mistake I have made.

Comment: Why do you solve this by using views? Easy doing by just have one nav template and switching `$state.current` in your controller.

Comment: I am new to angular. I tried to use single unnamed view and hardcore the map element but could not find how to remove view when I wanted to navigate from about back to map. Could you please give an example of your suggested approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO no need for stacking views in your case. Just create one view for `about` like in this [runnable plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/WengQpCsDtcbEWGmRm4Y?p=preview). This is a simple solution to achieve what you are asking for.

#### Main View

```
<div>
     <div>
         <span style="width:100px" ui-sref="PageTab"><a href="">Home</a></span>
         <span style="width:100px" ui-sref=".about"><a href="">About</a></span>
     </div>
     <ng-include src="'map.html'"></ng-include>
     <div>
         <div ui-view=""></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/PageTab");

    $stateProvider
        .state("PageTab", {
            url: "/PageTab",
            templateUrl: "mainTemplate.html"
        })
        .state("PageTab.about", {
            url: "/about",
            templateUrl: "about.html"
        })
});
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for all moorning, thanks! Quick question thou - "map content" actually gonna be google map. And I want it to initianated just once. Does your solution provide that by clicking on "about" user actually does not navigate away from "map content"?

Comment: @KārlisJanisels Yes, it will stay. =)

Comment: Great, thank you again. Still I am interested in behavior of multiple view that I descriebed in question... Would like to understand this more because I sure know that I will be using angularJS in other projects as well

Comment: Could you help me a bit again? I tried changing templateUrl to component when declaring route states but it breaks all logic. I createad component  `myApp.component("mapComp", {
  templateUrl: "mainTemplate.html"
});`  and changed `.state("PageTab", {
            url: "/PageTab",
            component: "mapComp"
        })`

Comment: @KārlisJanisels Yea sure, please create a new question and link it here. I will help ya inside this new questions.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048779/how-to-use-component-with-ui-router-angularjs)