# How to use component templates with ui-router AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am experiencing problems with ui-router. If I change from template to component suddenly all routing breaks.

app.module.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('jigup', [
        'ui.router',
        'map',
    ]);
})();
```

app.config.js

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('jigup')
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/map");
            $stateProvider
                .state("map", {
                    url: "/map",
                    template: '<span style="width:100px" ui-sref="map"><a href="">map</a></span><span style="width:100px" ui-sref=".about"><a href="">About</a></span> this is map <div ui-view=""></div>'
                })
                .state("map.about", {
                    url: "/about",
                    template: "about page"
                })
        });     
})();
```

and index.html:

```
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.4.1/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="jigup">
        <div data-ui-view=""></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.module.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.config.js'); ?>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And routing gives me that map is allways displayed but about only if neccessary.

I then tried to change code a bit:
app.config.js:

```
..
.state("map", {
    url: "/map",
    component: 'mapComponent'
})
...
```

and added files:

map.module.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('map', []);
})();
```

map.component.js:

```
    (function(){
        angular.module('map')
            .component('mapComponent', {
                template: '<span style="width:100px" ui-sref="map"><a href="">map</a></span><span style="width:100px" ui-sref=".about"><a href="">About</a></span> this is map <div ui-view=""></div>',
            });
   })();
```

but routing now breaks - I get blank page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component templates in `ui-router` are not supported in `v0.4.2` or earlier. You need to switch to the current RC candidate `1.0.0-rc.1` like in this [runnable plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/fanfBYe24Gig1PbfuvFV?p=preview).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-rc.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/PageTab");

    $stateProvider
        .state("PageTab", {
            url: "/PageTab",
            templateUrl: "mainTemplate.html"
        })
        .state("PageTab.about", {
            url: "/about",
            component: "about"
         }) 
});

myApp.component('about', {
  template: `<div>
                 <div>
                     <h1>About page</h1>
                 </div>
            </div>`
})
```